Simba ODBC Driver for Google Big Query DSN Setup on Windows
getting the "SSL verification failed because the server host name specified for the connection does not match the "CN" entry in the "Subject" field for the connection does not match the "CN" entry in the "Subject" field or any of the "DNS Name" entries of the "Subject Alternative Name" field in the server certificate.""
CN for Simba's ODBC Driver shows "Global Sign Root CA".



There could be an issue with the .pem file in use. Modify the .pem file  and add the certificate content of Cloud Services in the pem file. add the certificate key for the missing certificate.  Now selects the modified certificate and provides its path in the "Trusted Certificate" option and  further clicks on "UseSystemTrustStore". Let me know if this helps or not , waiting for your reply .

where can i get the correct .pem file?

Hi , I have posted an answer, if you find it helpful, please do consider upvoting and accepting it as per  stackoverflow guidelines  helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer

I only encounter the issue on my work laptop. It works perfectly on my personal system. There might be a firewall block at the organizational level.

PEM is a file format that may consist of a certificate  . You can find it on your local machine . copy the Cloud Service root certificate into the PEM file - then it works . https://snipboard.io/WpcHUG.jpg - something like this.
As i have already mentioned, there could be an issue with the .pem file in use. Modify the .pem file  and add the certificate content of Cloud Services in the pem file . add the certificate key for the missing certificate. Now selects the modified certificate and provides its path in the "Trusted Certificate" option and further clicks on "UseSystemTrustStore"
